# Jenkins agent container is failing to init:

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose configuration:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins-ansible
    build: ansible
    restart: on-failure
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 5000:5000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - /home/juliano/workspace/docker-projects/jenkins/volume/:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
  jenkins-agent-1:
    build:
      context: jenkins-agent
    restart: on-failure
    expose:
      - "22"
    container_name: jenkins-agent-1
    environment:
      - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=ssh-rsa omitted
      - JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
    volumes:
      - /home/juliano/workspace/docker-projects/jenkins/volume/:/var/jenkins_home
  jenkins-agent-2:
    # image: jenkins/ssh-agent:jdk11
    build:
      context: jenkins-agent
    restart: on-failure
    expose:
      - "22"
    container_name: jenkins-agent-2
    environment:
      - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=ssh-rsa omitted
      - JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
    volumes:
      - /home/juliano/workspace/docker-projects/jenkins/volume/:/var/jenkins_home
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: ubuntu18.04
```

And I'm receiving the following error message:

```
+ env
+ [[ ssh-rsa omitted == ssh-* ]]
+ write_key 'ssh-rsa omitted'
+ local ID_GROUP
++ stat -c %U:%G /home/jenkins
+ ID_GROUP=jenkins:jenkins
+ mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.ssh
+ echo 'ssh-rsa omitted'
+ chown -Rf jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins/.ssh
+ chmod 0700 -R /home/jenkins/.ssh
+ [[ '' == ssh-* ]]
+ env
+ grep _
/usr/local/bin/setup-sshd: line 54: /etc/environment: Permission denied
```

The jenkins-agent dockerfile is:

```
FROM jenkins/ssh-agent

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3 -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN apt-get install python3-distutils -y
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python3 get-pip.py && \
    pip install ansible --upgrade

USER jenkins
```

Previously, I was using jenkins/ssh-agent:jdk11 to build the agents and it was working well. Then I unsuccessfully tried to install Ansible into the agents through the jenkins-agent Dockerfile (receiving the aforementioned error). Now, even if I change jenkins-agent to jenkins/ssh-agent:jdk11, it is incurring the same problem.

Anyone could kindly help me, please?

Comment: what is the error ? you are getting ?

Comment: @codeaprendiz the error is at the end of the output of (I suppose) `docker-compose up`: `/usr/local/bin/setup-sshd: line 54: /etc/environment: Permission denied`

Comment: Did not spend much time but apparently the base image you are using does not support running with an other user than root. The entrypoint (`/usr/local/bin/setup-sshd`) needs to write env vars in `/etc/environment` which is writable by container root user only. Since this image runs with root user by default, you can simply drop both of your `USER` stanza in your Dockerfile as a quick fix. If you really want to run as `jenkins` inside the image, you'll need a bit more work but I really don't think it is worth in such case (it's running sshd inside a container and master connects as `jenkins`)

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator :) . Moreover not sure if `jenkins-ansible` is custom image or not. I could find only https://hub.docker.com/r/avastmick/ansible-jenkins which seems to be 4 years old now.

Comment: When it comes to ansible, I only trust pip as a source of truth and that's the only way I use to install. It takes less that  a minute to complete, no need to put anything else in the way and you can decide which collections / python modules you want to have.

Comment: Regarding the ansible-jenkins image you linked: I don't know what you call "custom". What I know is that I have no idea wh.o.at is "avastmick" who published 6 images on dockerhub with the youngest update accross all of them being 4 years ago. In the mean time ansible and jenkins have EOL many realeases and I don't need to run that image to know it's totally deprecated for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the *jenkins-agent/Dockerfile* and removed *USER root* and *USER jenkins*.

Now it is working.